# flutter app crashes with no reason : E/Surface ( 6317): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

When I was developing a flutter app, this error appeared:

> E/Surface ( 6317): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
>       W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 6317): : failed to queueBuffer
>       W/Adreno-EGL( 6317): : EGL_BAD_SURFACE

I tried deleting the build manually and using `flutter clean`. I also restarted android studio and disabled hardware acceleration, but nothing has worked.

Any help would be great. 
 Thanks .

Comment: I am facing same issue when using google maps and geocoding